# Do these properties imply full rank?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, matrices

Assume that we have a $M\times N$ matrix $P$ (where $M=N$):

\begin{bmatrix}
p_{1,1} & \ldots & p_{1,n} & p_{1,n+1} & \ldots & p_{1,N}\\
\vdots &  & \vdots & \vdots &  & \vdots\\
p_{m,1} & \ldots & p_{m,n} & p_{m,n+1} & \ldots & p_{m,N}\\
\vdots &  & \vdots & \vdots &  & \vdots\\
p_{M,1} & \ldots & p_{M,n} & p_{M,n+1} & \ldots & p_{M,N}%
 \end{bmatrix}

Do the following conditions guarantee that $P$ has full rank?

- Every column contains a set of non-zero probabilities that add up to
  one. (so $\sum_{m=1}^{M}p_{m,n}=1$).
- If we compare two adjacent columns, say $n$ and $n+1$, then there exists
  some $m^{\ast}$ (where $1<m^{\ast}\leq M$) such that $p_{m,n+1}<p_{m,n}$ if
  $m<m^{\ast}$ and $p_{m,n+1}>p_{m,n}$ if $m\geq m^{\ast}$ (so the mass of the
  probabilities is shifted towards higher values of $m$). Moreover, $m^{\ast}$
  is weakly increasing in $n$.

Example of $P$:

\begin{bmatrix}
0.0156 & 0.0039 & 0.0010 & 0.0002\\
0.3282 & 0.1758 & 0.0908 & 0.0462\\
0.5625 & 0.5859 & 0.5273 & 0.4409\\
0.0937 & 0.2344 & 0.3809 & 0.5127
 \end{bmatrix}

One of the things I have tried is to show that all columns are linearly
independent. This requires that

\begin{array}
[c]{c}%
c_{1}p_{1,1}+\ldots+c_{N}p_{1,N}=0\\
\vdots\\
c_{1}p_{M,1}+\ldots+c_{N}p_{M,N}=0
\end{array}

holds only for the zero vector. By summing these equations and using that
$\sum_{m=1}^{M}p_{m,n}=1$, you can show that $\sum_{i=1}^{N}c_{i}%
=0$. Moreover, since all $p_{m,n}>0$, then if some $c_{i}>0$ we need that at
least one $c_{j}<0$. However, I'm not sure where to go from there (and how to
use the information from the second bullet point).

Really appreciate any suggestions to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance.